# Function returns a wrong number C++

Tags: c++, function

I've got a problem. Inside function "pop" , int rezultat has correct value, but outside, is 0. I don't know C++, but i have to do this for school, it took me 2 hours and i have no idea what I'm doing wrong... please help.

```
#include <iostream>
int rezultat;

struct stosik {
    int x;
    stosik *next;
};

void push(stosik* &stos, int x) {
    stosik* tymczasowy = new stosik; 
    tymczasowy->x = x;
    tymczasowy->next = stos;
    stos=tymczasowy;
    delete tymczasowy;
}

bool isEmpty(stosik* stos){
    return stos != NULL;
}

//HERE@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
bool pop(stosik* &stos, int rezultat){
    if (!isEmpty(stos))     {
        return false;
    }
    stosik* tymczasowy = stos;
    rezultat =  tymczasowy -> x;

    if(stos->next !=NULL){ 
        tymczasowy = stos -> next;
        stos=tymczasowy;
    }
    else {
            std::cout << "Nic" << std::endl;
    }
//        delete tymczasowy;
    std::cout <<"Rezultat na koncu dziala funkcji "<<rezultat << std::endl;
    return true;
}


bool topEl(stosik* &stos,  int* result, int mekeke){
    if (isEmpty(stos))
    {
        return false;
    }

    *result = stos ->x;
    mekeke=*result;

    return true;        
}


int main(){ 
    stosik* stos_roboczy=NULL; // deklaracja stosu, domyślnie NULL

    std::cout << "0 empty, 1 something "<< std::endl;
    std::cout << isEmpty(stos_roboczy) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "" << std::endl;   


    push(stos_roboczy, 5);
    push(stos_roboczy, 15);
    push(stos_roboczy, 25);

    std::cout << "0 empty, 1 something<<std::endl;
    std::cout << isEmpty(stos_roboczy) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "" << std::endl;


//AND HERE @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

    pop(stos_roboczy, rezultat);
    std::cout <<"Wrong result after function: "<<rezultat << std::endl;



//        
//        pop(stos_roboczy, rezultat);
//        pop(stos_roboczy, rezultat);
//        
//        std::cout << rezultat << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean wrong number? You're returning true or false, what else are you expecting? And as a future tip, program in English. It's the universal programming Language.

Comment: i mean integer "rezultat". It is declared global, inside pop function it has a value assigned by "rezultat=tymczasowy->x", inside is correct(25), but in  next line in "main()", value is "0".  Like this: http://imgur.com/j5NtVJI

Comment: I recommend using a debugger and single stepping through the code.  Also, print variable values or *watch* them as each statement is executed.

Comment: When you have the code working you should get a [code review](codereview.stackexchange.com) to get best practice for C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two different ints which both happen to have the same name: The global `rezultat` declared at the top of the file, and the function parameter `rezultat` in the parameter list for function `pop()`.

You pass the value of the global `rezultat` into `pop()`, then you assign a new value to the function parameter `rezultat` inside the function. When the function exits, the function parameter `rezultat` is gone. You didn't assign a new value to the global `rezultat`, so it has the same value as it did before.

If you want to send the value of a variable from inside a function to the outside, use the `return` statement.

If you rename the global one to something else, that should clear up your confusion between the two.

Also, see [@ForeverStudent's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776259/424129). He spotted a number of other issues that you'll need to take a look at.

Comment: Correct, but doesn't address the memory leak you have in push, you need to rethink that function entirely

Comment: @ForeverStudent *Who* needs to rethink that function (ha ha)?! I was only addressing the bug he knows about. Your answer is much better than mine for that reason.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, sorry The OP needs to rethink the function not you. my apologies for confusion haha

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few problems with your code.

First of all, your `push` function has the signature `void push(stosik* &stos, int x)`

based on your semantics you most likely want `void push(stosik* stos, int x)`

You have the same problem in the signature of `pop`

also inside the body of `push` you have:

```
stosik* tymczasowy = new stosik; //allocate on heap, OK
tymczasowy->x = x; //OK
tymczasowy->next = stos;//OK
stos=tymczasowy;  //BOTH pointers now point to the same memory
delete tymczasowy;//you are freeing memory for both. 
//stos->next is now inaccessible and leaked
```

last line creates a memory leak, both pointers are pointing to the same location and you are freeing the memory. sure you still have the pointer, but it is no longer pointing to a valid object instance.

Also you are using extern global variable `rezultat` that will be initialized to 0.

Now your `pop` function has a formal parameter of the same name. 
This causes `rezultat` to refer to the variable in the function scope as opposed to the global.

I would advise you to avoid using global variables, but if you have to use them, at least do not overwrite them in block scopes.

```
bool pop(stosik* stos, int rezultat) //valid code, but terrible practice
{
    //here rezultat refers to the variable passed in NOT the global
    //global variable is still accessible in this scope via ::rezultat

    if (!isEmpty(stos))    
    {
        return false;
    }
    stosik* tymczasowy = stos;
    rezultat =  tymczasowy -> x; 
    //this rezultat will be destroyed when this function returns. 
...
}
```

If you decide to be naughty and use global variables, then you will need to do this:

```
bool pop(stosik* stos) 
{
    if (!isEmpty(stos))    
    {
        return false;
    }
    stosik* tymczasowy = stos;
    rezultat =  tymczasowy -> x; 
    //now this refers to the global variable
 ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to return a value through a parameter, you need to use a reference, e.g.

```
bool pop(stosik* &stos, int &rezultat){
```

Note the `&` before `rezultat`.
When you call `pop(stos_roboczy, rezultat);`, this will put a reference to `rezultat` on the stack instead of its value. And it allows the function to return the given value to the variable of the caller, instead of just modifying a local variable/parameter.

See also [Passing arguments by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) for more details.